# Get the bare URL for an attachment 

Tags: attachments, urls, images

I'm trying to get the link to the thumbnail size of an attachment image.

I tried this:

```
wp_get_attachment_link( $img_id, 'thumbnail' );
```

but it returns the actual HTML for the image wrapped in a link. I want just the bare URL directly to that size image.

Does Wordpress have a different function I should be using, or do I have to extract it from the HTML returned by `wp_get_attachment_link`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)?

Using `wp_get_attachment_image_src`:

```
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img_id, 'thumbnail' );
$src = $src[0]; // Grabs only the URL ($src[1] = width of image, $src[2] = height of image)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I needed. I swear I searched through the Codex before asking here. Somehow I feel that the Codex is not properly (read: messy) organized.